# Access a WEB API service remotely?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, service, remote-access

I am searching for a way to host either a WEB API service, a WCF service, or an OWIN self hosted service that is running on a different machine on my network. I have created all three of the services, and they work 100% locally.

I am not a networking guru, but am willing to try anything.

I have all of the services running on [Machine1] and can get results back from 'http://localhost:8514/api/controller'.

On [Machine2] I have only been able to see an IIS blank(*which I edited with a unique message to confirm it's my machine) page by going to 'http://[Machine1]' but cant get to any actual endpoints.

**I have used the IIS Manager to override the 404 errors to purple.com, which is unique enough to confirm that I am indeed looking into [Machine1] remotely, but still not able to figure out what the URL should be.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I don't see how this helps

Comment: It's a tool to access web services. Add some details to your question.